# Error when starting Spyder IDE on Python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, spyder

I am trying to install and run spyder IDE on MacBook Pro M1 but its not working, here is the error that I am getting:

```
MacBook-Pro ~ % spyder
Layer-backing can not be explicitly controlled on 10.14 when built against the 10.14 SDK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/spyder", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 236, in main
    mainwindow.main(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 1992, in main
    mainwindow = create_window(MainWindow, app, splash, options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/app/utils.py", line 281, in create_window
    main.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 875, in setup
    PLUGIN_REGISTRY.register_plugin(self, PluginClass,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/api/plugin_registration/registry.py", line 274, in register_plugin
    instance = self._instantiate_spyder5_plugin(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/api/plugin_registration/registry.py", line 152, in _instantiate_spyder5_plugin
    plugin_instance = PluginClass(main_window, configuration=CONF)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/api/plugins/new_api.py", line 294, in __init__
    self._container = container = self.CONTAINER_CLASS(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/plugins/tours/container.py", line 48, in __init__
    self._tour_dialog = OpenTourDialog(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/plugins/tours/widgets.py", line 1074, in __init__
    image = image.scaled(image_width, image_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  scaled(self, int, int, aspectRatioMode: Qt.AspectRatioMode = Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, transformMode: Qt.TransformationMode = Qt.FastTransformation): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  scaled(self, QSize, aspectRatioMode: Qt.AspectRatioMode = Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, transformMode: Qt.TransformationMode = Qt.FastTransformation): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This error was fixed in our **5.2.0** version, released in November 2021.